# Java-AffineTransform API:Scale an image to maximum of 300*100 pixels with?

Tags: java, 2d, affinetransform

I know to do simple scaling, but how can i scale an image to a maximum of 300*100 pixels? i searched the AffineTransform API class but couldn't find a method for this.

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would need to "back into" your scale factor by figuring what scale will get your height to 300 pixels and your width to 100.

Something like

```
double xScale = 100/image.getWidth();
double yScale = 300/image.getHeight();

AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.setToScale( xScale, yScale );
//paint code goes here
```

This will not scale it uniformly though.  To do that you need to use the same scale for x and y.   So if you are trying to ensure your image fits on a screen/display/page you would take the widest dimension's scale.
so to use the above example...

```
double xScale = 100/image.getWidth();
double yScale = 300/image.getHeight();
double theScale = xScale > yScale ? xScale : yScale;

AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();
transform.setToScale( theScale , theScale );
//paint code goes here
```

This is just a suggestion though, hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much...i also used AffineTransformOp to filter the image..thx

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the factors for the transform based on the image width/height relative to the target width/height.

Write some code and if you hit a problem, ask a specific question.